# Apple Mach-o Linker Error Cocoa Pods AFNetworking iOS 7.x.x & iOS 8.x.x

Tags: xcode, linker, cocoapods, afnetworking-2, mach-o

After debugging in iOS 6 I tried to go back to debugging in iOS 7 however now I keep getting the following build errors. I have tried searching Google, Stack Overflow, Apple Dev Forums but sadly all suggestions don't seem to work. Xcode allows me to build an Archive and that works fine on a real device, but I am having issues when trying to run on the software or the real device when in debugging. Any Ideas?

I deleted and re-added the pod by running "pods installs" in the app folder, cleaning the build, sadly to no success. I have also checked all the build settings for all targets and to my knowledge all the correct architectures are present. I have tried the "select valid architectures and press delete" but nothing changed.

Build Errors:

```
Pods-AppName was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods-AppName.a' because its architectures 'i386' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386 x86_64'

ld: library not found for -lPods-AppName
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thank you in advance for any potential help.